# Expandable listview Refreshing

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am using expandable listview i need to refresh as i am searching the list only for parent.I have searched for tutorial in which i can set visibility only for some parent but not all the expandable listview object .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess u can implement slowadapter for ur listview.

check this slow adapter in apidemos example.

Comment: I have custumized the view and added a check box in layout sl after clicking the childrens of respective parent i should get the respective child index also .....? how to achieve that in  slowadapter  ?

Comment: go through the slowadapter example which is in ApiDemos sample.